# Wearable platform with display

Tags: linux, embedded-systems, gps, wearable-technology

I am looking for a wrist-wearable development platform solution with the following specs:

- Some kind of a display that you can see in the dark as well as in bright sunlight.
- Hardware buttons (as opposed to touch-screen).
- User-programmable on the CPU level (ideally in C).
- ANT+
- WiFi
- Low-power
- Low-cost
- CPU does not have to be awfully fast, 100MHz would be plenty
- Somewhat documented interface with working examples
- It would be nice if the board could run Linux
- It would be nice if it also had a GPS chip
- Something that can be mass-produced at some point to turn into a commercial product.

The best I've been able to find on the market is so far Motorola's MotoACTV which becomes an OK development platform once you root it, but it has a few problems:

- Definitely not low-power. With display on, and WiFi/GPS/Ant+ sensors off, it lasts maybe only 8 hours. With GPS on only 3.
- To interface with display and buttons you pretty much have to go through Android as bypassing it creates some serious hurdles - mostly due to the lack of documentation/examples.
- ANT+ interface is a beast to get working as you have to reverse engineer a lot due to the lack of documentation. I have made some progress there, but have not yet been able to actually obtain the signal.
- With GPS you are stuck with the Motorola driver which has some serious issues - sometimes it takes 30 minutes to get the signal, then the signal is often not very accurate. I have made an effort to bypass it and write my own, made some progress, but this is another uphill reverse-engineering battle again to due the lack of documentation/examples.
- Even if I get everything to work perfectly, this is not a viable commercial development platform.

Ti has Chronos EZ-430 which is sort of in the area, but it is lacking some  capabilities. It might be possible to instrument it with WiFi/Ant+, but if so, I lack the hardware expertise.

Any ideas on how to build my "dream" gadget would be appreciated - either  pre-made product, or a list of parts/instructions how to put them together including the box/wrist-band to make it wrist-wearable.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with this kind of hardware, but have you looked at all at what Adafruit offers?  They have quite a few products that might be a fit.  Of course its something you'd have to build yourself.

Comment: There are a lot of raw components on the market, and I am sure with enough hardware experience you can easily tell which ones you will need for this project and how to connect them. What I am looking for is some specific hardware expertise - what exactly to get and what to connect to what.

Comment: I don't think this is the place to find how-to guides, though.

Comment: Did you every find something? ESP32 would probably do it, except for the GPS. You can buy a wrist mounted M5stack ESp32 with display for under $115

Comment: Sorry, typo. That ought to have said under $15

Answer (score 1):

$14.95 will get you [this](https://m5stack-store.myshopify.com/products/stick):

[image]

It has a plug & play Grove connector, so you can easily add on [GPS](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000494209347.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.740c5589SzuFmP&algo_pvid=0655a1a4-a42e-4e66-952e-747ceef679ce&algo_expid=0655a1a4-a42e-4e66-952e-747ceef679ce-0&btsid=2100bb5116160762560866373ec4ef&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) for a further $12.

If you can live without GPS, or can solder, then I also recommend LilyGo.

They have a slim [wristband](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000550284680.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.252e3f9cKVjjPh&algo_pvid=968b998a-dee8-46be-bacb-dc495cada521&algo_expid=968b998a-dee8-46be-bacb-dc495cada521-4&btsid=0b0a0ac216160764316683134e28ff&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_), like an activity tracker for about $20:

[image]

and a [wristwatch](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000971508364.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.252e3f9cKVjjPh&algo_pvid=968b998a-dee8-46be-bacb-dc495cada521&algo_expid=968b998a-dee8-46be-bacb-dc495cada521-0&btsid=0b0a0ac216160764316683134e28ff&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) with a larger screen for about $25:

[image]

All three of these are ESP32 based, so have WiFi and BlueTooth, and are fully programmable.

If, like me, you are allergic to soldering, the M5stack has a Grove connector which allows plug & play of 300+ sensors, motors, etc